# Connection Problem with Cutecom Serial Terminal

Tags: 12.04, serial-port

I am using [cutecom](http://cutecom.sourceforge.net/) for sending serial commands to my FTDI Device, which is connected in `/dev/ttyUSB0`. But I am unable to connect through Cutecom and input text box is disabled.

When I am pressing Open Device it is unable to open `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

I checked through `lsusb`, the FTDI Device is connected. Why it is so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is frequently caused by permissions on the serial devices.  Is there any change if you run cutecom as root?  If so, adding your user account to the 'dialout' group ought to do the trick.